# Is there a way to make a custom orderBy in Drupal query

Tags: drupal-7

Im going to order my table by a custom status order 0,4,1,2,3 and have no clue how to do this with drupal query

when doing it with mysql i can

```
select * from table order by field(status, 0,4,1,2,3)
```

is there any way to do this with drupal?

```
$query->orderBy('status', array(0,4,1,2,3));
```

or something?

Answer (score 3):

I've faced with it many years ago. And I found solution for Drupal 7 like:

```
$query->orderBy('FIELD(node.nid, 5,12,3,6)', 'ASC');
```

Probably it will work for you.
As I remeber I've found it [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2011-12-23/mysql-order-by-field-my_fields-and)

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work with 
    $query->orderBy('FIELD(submissions.status', 0,4,1,2,3)', 'ASC');

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'submissions.status' in 'order clause': SELECT sfs.* FROM {submissions} sfs ORDER BY status ASC, FIELD(submissions.status, 0,4,1,2,3) ASC; Array ( )

Comment: @lukee Hey, it looks like you have extra ' after "FIELD(submissions.status".

Comment: @lukee Probably you used example from my link. If you will look on it once more, you will see that there is some correction about extras ' symbol (or compare yours and mine string)